# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Apache SVN endpoint

Tags: javascript, apache, svn, get, xmlhttprequest

I would like to make a XmlHttp GET request from client Javascript to a Apache SVN endpoint and I'm facing the following error:

> Failed to load http://IP_ADDRESS/svn/: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://IP_ADDRESS:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I've tried set the `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the following files and no success so far.

- `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf` (the  configuration is inside this file)
- `.htaccess` (inside the endpoint root folder)

I'm running out of ideias how to do it.

The Javascript request code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// encodedData = ...
xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedData);
xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
xmlhttp.send();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the address of the client instead of *?

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://IP_ADDRESS:3000"
```

Also if it doesn't work I would suggest adding these other options:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  "true"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods  "POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers  "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
```

Comment: thanks @QuentinG although I have a question: is it right divide by , or : or just space?

Comment: My example comes from a node.js server it looks like this :
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");